# Highlight specific cell of datagridview based on previous cell value matching header

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, paint

I am having a strange issue I hope someone can help me with. I have a winform that has series of datagridviews in it. A separate set of programming takes the cells selected by the user in a specific dgv and inserts the data into a database table. A stored procedure is then called to validate the data in the table (and then do other things). If the STP finds issues, it writes them to an error table and reports back to the user which columns failed validation.

The user then has the option to view the error log, which opens a new form that has a datagridview that is populated with the results of the error table populated by the stored procedure.

The second column in the table stores the name of the field that failed the validation. Subsequent columns in this view represent each item from the originating table the validation was done against, and their header values match the column names exactly.

What I am trying to do is paint the background of the cell that has the problematic value in it, but for some reason, one of the columns has all its cells getting re-painted even when the column header doesn't match. The rest of the cells paint perfectly.

This may be easier for me to describe with some visual aide, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to post any images =\ So, picture if you will, a datagridview that has two static columns, one called TableName, the other ErrorColumn. ErrorColumn denotes the field name that failed validation, for example say I had two rows that failed, one for "Status", the other for "Description". Two rows would exist, each with a distinct ErrorColumn value, one that has Status, the other row Description.

For row 1, the ErrorColumn value is "Description". What I am trying to do is highlight the cell of the Description column in red on that row so the problematic value is easy to find. This works OK at this point, but when row 2 is rendered, which has an ErrorColumn value of Status, not only does that row highlight the cell under the related Status column, but it also highlights the cell under the Description column. If I had 3 or 4 or however many rows, all of them get the Description column cells highlighted in addition to their actual cells. The Description column cells should only highlight if the row's ErrorColumn value is "Description".

I hope that I was able to convey what I am going for here.

Here is the method I am using to perform these duties. I can't figure out what is causing my issue, or a better way to achieve this, and hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
    private void colorErrorCells(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args)
    {
        string head = this.dataGridView1.Columns[args.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
        if (head == dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[args.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the long-winded post!

Answer (score 0):

uggg...this is what happens when you try to program too many hours in a day. I just fixed it by adding an else clause to my if and set the backcolor to White...problem solved. Sorry for wasting anyone's time